# Invalid property value after deploying in Prodction Environment

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm a bit puzzled why this happening in different server environment.

I have a global css class declared in my `style.scss` in my Angular application. This class was used in different pages with data entry form.

```
.form-container ) > * { 
      width: 100%: 
      padding : 1.25rem !important 1.25rem; 
 }
```

If you can see, there's indeed something wrong with the value of `padding` where, `!important` was placed before the last value.

Below how it looks like when I inspect it in dev tool.

**Pre Production**
[image]

**Production**
[image]

As you can see, in Pre Production, it was strike through which means, padding was not applied in my website where I used the said class. However, on the other snip (Production) it became valid value but, the last value `1.25rem` was omitted.

I would like to know why in Production does not complain with the value of `padding` but in Pre Production it does?

I suspect maybe this is something to do when bundling the angular app using **ng build --prod**, BUT not really sure why this happened.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!important` must always be mentioned at the end of a definition.

The below definition is actually invalid so the browser ignores it.

```
padding : 1.25rem !important 1.25rem;
```

Whereas the packager/minifier detects the `!important` and calls it as the end of the definition. It is working as expected.

It is doing the right thing by removing everything beyond the `!important` marker to make the definition valid.